# Salesforce IDE Pluse Installer download failure

Tags: eclipse, ide, salesforce, force.com, pulse

I'm trying to install the salesforce IDE via the pulse installer it all goes swimmingly except for a final 27.8kb that is listed as

"org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86"

I'm assuming this resource has a binary extension and is therefore being blocked by my company firewall.

I've poked around the mirror sites it tries to connect to but can't find anything with a similar name to this.

Is there any way I can directly access these files and download them manually?

---

I ended up gettting the old helios build and the plugin as suggested by mmix, sadly the firewall as still being picky about downloading them so I was able to create a mirror on a non-firewalled machine using

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ -destination .\sfdcplugin
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ -destination .\sfdcplugin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of eclipse :)

Anyway, you can just download the whole enchilada from the salesforce site, its a prepackaged eclipse with everything ForceIDE might need.

Choose a standalone version from [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation)

If that still leaves you in the jam, try to download rich client package externally and install it into eclipse before hand. I think [this](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2) is the Helios SR2 build.

Comment: Sadly I don't need a welcome I have had 'experience' of this ide previously :( I did in fact try the full prepackaged version but that uses the pulse installer to get additional components and is failing, I'm giving the full eclipse install and salesforce plugin route a go now and will report back.